# Proper way to conditionally wrap markup in a div in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to wrap some markup in a div if a certain condition is true, so I've crafted the (horrible) code below.

There must be a better way to wrap some div tags or similar around a block depending on a condition. Anyone knows any such way?

The example below is of course simplified to the extreme.

In code-behind:

```
if(something)
{
    wrapperTop.Visible = wrapperBottom.Visible = true;
}
```

In declarative markup:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Visible="False" ID="wrapperTop">
    <div class="wrapdiv">
</asp:Literal>
    Lorem ipsum etc.
<asp:Literal runat="server" Visible="False" ID="wrapperBottom">
    </div>
</asp:Literal>
```

Comment: `wrapperTop.Visible = wrapperBottom.Visible = something`... ;-)

Comment: Would also do the trick... :)

Comment: Did you ever find a good answer? Looking to solve the same issue and currently falling back to similarly nasty code!

Comment: @getsetcode: nope :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the blank div tag, you can wrap with Panel on design time.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1">
    Lorem ipsum etc.
</asp:Panel>

if(something)
{
    Panel1.CssClass = "wrapdiv";
}
```

Comment: The example is trivial, the wrapper can actually consist of a whole bunch of different tags.